# Can I setup static routes through ILO card?

Tags: windows-server-2008, blade-server, ilo

I am setting up a network and I have an HP Blade 380 G7 server with its own ILO module.  I am going to be giving users access to this box and have segmented the ILO card off.  I am wondering 2 things.

1.) I am an administrator on box can I use the ILO network port to gain access to that network segment?
2.) can I access the ILO itself?

to question 2 this is merely an access question I know I can add user IDs to the ILO with admin to the box but can I access the ILO directly even though its on a different network segment?

Any assistance you can provide on this would be helpful.

Comment: What are you asking? This is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The DL380's not a blade, it's a rack-mount server - or do you mean a BL460 which is the blade equivalent? Now onto your questions.

The iLO module is completely separate from the server itself, you could be an administrator or  root but there's no normal/easy way to get data from the host OS out over the iLO port. I'm sure some hacker with intimiate knowledge of iLO firmware could do something along those lines as a challenge but it's not what it's there for and there's no realistic way to do it.

Your second question is easier and the answer is simply yes, if there's a route to it. So for instance if both the iLO and one of the regular NICs were configured correctly and on the same VLAN then you should be able to communicate easily, the same is true across correctly configured routed networks too. The iLO's ethernet port and IP stack are absolutely regular in their implementation so can be treated as another server or client in that respect. In fact I've been known to access iLO from a host OS just like this as a quick way to mount an ISO file before now.